# Edges only listed unidirectional in vertices. Bug?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

Just migrated to OrientDB 2.2.3 I am experiencing some problems with edges and vertices lookup.

As depicted in the [Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQwvv.png) I have two vertices `#20:0` and `#20:3` connected to each other via the edges `#24:452 (#20:3 -> #20:0)` and `#24:453` `(#20:0 -> #20:3)`. However only vertex `#20:3` lists the edges as in / out edge?

Have I missed something? Recreating fails, since a Unique out/in index prevents orientdb from creating duplicates. From a first inspection it looks like the `OMultiCollectionIterator` used in `OrientVertex.getEdges` does not return the proper amount of edges.

I am thankful for all kind of help.

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQwvv.png)

Comment: Hi @Fritz can you open an issue?

Comment: Hi @MichelaBonizzi, for sure. Same content as above?

Comment: Hi @MichelaBonizzi, done! Created the issue https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6401.